# How can I get started in game development, and what language is best for beginners?

Tags: game-industry

I'm very interested in game development, and I'd like to start on some basics. Sorry if this is a poor question, this is my first time on StackExchange.

Comment: "what language" questions are off-topic as per the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

I'd say c++ with SDL is a good place to start.

SDL is a library that helps you manage input with keyboard, mouse, draws you the window you need for the game, and handles alot of the little details you don't need/want to know as a beginner, abstracting all that to give you a quick and simple framework to work on for a beginner.

Get SDL here: http://www.libsdl.org/
Use Code::Blocks or some other IDE. I like CB myself.

Comment: Isn't C++ a bit too extreme for a beginner? He did not state anything about his past programming experience.

Comment: I don't think it is... I'm an inexperienced programmer and c++ wasn't different from learning abit of Java, the only other language I know (besides assembly, doesn't count), and there's tons tutorials around on c++ easy to understand... but if you have a better suggestion go ahead, idk :)